# Where in Middle Earth is the Paths of the Dead?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-lord-of-the-rings

The Paths of the Dead is where Aragorn, Legolas and Gimli go to recruit the undead army to fight for Gondor.

The most detailed map of Middle Earth I could find is [here](http://blog.lefigaro.fr/hightech/assets_c/2011/06/middle-earth-map-33096.html).

From reading on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paths_of_the_Dead) it mentions all the places it's near like Harrowdale and Dimholt but I can't find any of these on the map so I can't figure out where the Paths of the Dead is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The relevant information can be found in the Lord of the Rings wiki [here:](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/White_Mountains). The description places the mountains: 
*The White Mountains formed the northern boundary of Gondor and the southern boundary of Rohan except in their easternmost provinces, where Gondor's province of Anorien lay to the north of the mountains.*
The entrance to the Paths of the Dead is described as [Dwimorberg](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Dwimorberg).
[Harrowdale](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Harrowdale) is described as being near the Snowbourn River, hence on your map, near where the mountains and the river intersect, Edoras.